# CultureInfo: Difference between he-IL and he

Tags: .net, cultureinfo

I would like to know what the difference between the language codes "he-IL" and "he" is.
Thank you for any info!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`he-IL` is the Hebrew "language" as it spoken/used in the Israel "region". The addition of a region allows for localisation (both resources and formatting) specific to that region. `he` refers only to the language, abstract from any region.

There numerous languages (Hebrew, Japanese, Greek, etc) that only define one region so in practise there isn't much difference (outside potential future proofing).

Comment: `he-IL` is in a template of `<language>-<REGION>`. 
Languages which are in use in a few "regions" can be distinguished by the `<REGION>`.  
For example:
`en-AU` which is English (Australia) vs
`en-CA` which is English (Canada)
and so on.